# Selenium Retry if not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
 def carten(self):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="add-remove-buttons"]/input')))

    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="add-remove-buttons"]/input').click()
    time.sleep(0.9)
```

I want that when its not interactable python retry to click until its interactable.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in a while try/except:

```
while True:
  try:
    # something that might raise an error
    break
  except:
    pass
```